# Python program crashing silently

Tags: python, python-2.7, redis, python-multiprocessing, redis-py

My pseudo code in simplistic terms is like

```
cache = self.class_based_on_redis_py.StrictRedis
new_python_multiprocess = some_process(use_cache = cache)
```

This multiprocess runs a flask server and uses this cache inside it.
Now the issue is:

When I access cache out of multiprocess, it works fine.
When I use it inside multiprocess, it works fine.

But when I use it in multiprocess first, and then out of multiprocess in the same program, it crashes.

I used pdb debugger to track where exactly crash is happening.The crash happens when redis tries to send command and finally does `sock.sendall`.
As I checked the redis connection pool code, it does reset connections if it finds change in `pid`.But strangely in my case, when call comes from `multiprocess` code, the `pid` does not change.Is there a workaround for this?

Here are the pdb debug steps. After the last step the program simple stops without any error. I am running these through `nose -vs`.

```
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(949)exists()
-> def exists(self, name):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(951)exists()
-> return self.execute_command('EXISTS', name)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(661)execute_command()
-> def execute_command(self, *args, **options):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(663)execute_command()
-> pool = self.connection_pool
(Pdb) s
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(664)execute_command()
-> command_name = args[0]
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(665)execute_command()
-> connection = pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(959)get_connection()
-> def get_connection(self, command_name, *keys, **options):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(961)get_connection()
-> self._checkpid()
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(962)get_connection()
-> try:
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(963)get_connection()
-> connection = self._available_connections.pop()
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(966)get_connection()
-> self._in_use_connections.add(connection)
(Pdb) c
-> if not self.redis_conn.exists("{}:{}".format(self.redis_hash, prefix)):
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(949)exists()
-> def exists(self, name):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(951)exists()
-> return self.execute_command('EXISTS', name)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(661)execute_command()
-> def execute_command(self, *args, **options):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(663)execute_command()
-> pool = self.connection_pool
(Pdb) s
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(664)execute_command()
-> command_name = args[0]
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(665)execute_command()
-> connection = pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(959)get_connection()
-> def get_connection(self, command_name, *keys, **options):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(961)get_connection()
-> self._checkpid()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(949)_checkpid()
-> def _checkpid(self):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(950)_checkpid()
-> if self.pid != os.getpid():
(Pdb) self.pid
27855
(Pdb) os.getpid()
27855
(Pdb) c
multiprocess code was successful though i dont know why pid is same ... ok
direct access to cache out of multiprocess
-> if not self.redis_conn.exists("{}:{}".format(self.redis_hash, prefix)):
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(949)exists()
-> def exists(self, name):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(951)exists()
-> return self.execute_command('EXISTS', name)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(661)execute_command()
-> def execute_command(self, *args, **options):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(663)execute_command()
-> pool = self.connection_pool
(Pdb) s
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(664)execute_command()
-> command_name = args[0]
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(665)execute_command()
-> connection = pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(959)get_connection()
-> def get_connection(self, command_name, *keys, **options):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(961)get_connection()
-> self._checkpid()
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(949)_checkpid()
-> def _checkpid(self):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(950)_checkpid()
-> if self.pid != os.getpid():
(Pdb) os.getpid()
27855
(Pdb) self.pid
27855
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(950)_checkpid()->None
-> if self.pid != os.getpid():
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(962)get_connection()
-> try:
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(963)get_connection()
-> connection = self._available_connections.pop()
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(966)get_connection()
-> self._in_use_connections.add(connection)
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(967)get_connection()
-> return connection
(Pdb) n
--Return--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(967)get_connection()->Connecti...379,db=0>
-> return connection
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(666)execute_command()
-> try:
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/client.py(667)execute_command()
-> connection.send_command(*args)
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(608)send_command()
-> def send_command(self, *args):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(610)send_command()
-> self.send_packed_command(self.pack_command(*args))
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(632)pack_command()
-> def pack_command(self, *args):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(634)pack_command()
-> output = []
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(640)pack_command()
-> command = args[0]
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(641)pack_command()
-> if ' ' in command:
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(645)pack_command()
-> args = (Token.get_token(command),) + args[1:]
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(647)pack_command()
-> buff = SYM_EMPTY.join(
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(648)pack_command()
-> (SYM_STAR, b(str(len(args))), SYM_CRLF))
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(650)pack_command()
-> for arg in imap(self.encoder.encode, args):
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(653)pack_command()
-> if len(buff) > 6000 or len(arg) > 6000:
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(660)pack_command()
-> buff = SYM_EMPTY.join((buff, SYM_DOLLAR, b(str(len(arg))),
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(661)pack_command()
-> SYM_CRLF, arg, SYM_CRLF))
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(650)pack_command()
-> for arg in imap(self.encoder.encode, args):
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(653)pack_command()
-> if len(buff) > 6000 or len(arg) > 6000:
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(660)pack_command()
-> buff = SYM_EMPTY.join((buff, SYM_DOLLAR, b(str(len(arg))),
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(661)pack_command()
-> SYM_CRLF, arg, SYM_CRLF))
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(650)pack_command()
-> for arg in imap(self.encoder.encode, args):
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(662)pack_command()
-> output.append(buff)
(Pdb) 
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(663)pack_command()
-> return output
(Pdb) 
--Return--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(663)pack_command()->['*2\r\n$6\r\n...e:account\r\n']
-> return output
(Pdb) 
--Call--
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(582)send_packed_command()
-> def send_packed_command(self, command):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(584)send_packed_command()
-> if not self._sock:
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(586)send_packed_command()
-> try:
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(587)send_packed_command()
-> if isinstance(command, str):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(589)send_packed_command()
-> for item in command:
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/site-packages/redis/connection.py(590)send_packed_command()
-> self._sock.sendall(item)
(Pdb) item
'*2\r\n$6\r\nEXISTS\r\n$44\r\nd1d3d6be-c86d-4be7-9133-4452fd61d0de:account\r\n'
(Pdb) command
['*2\r\n$6\r\nEXISTS\r\n$44\r\nd1d3d6be-c86d-4be7-9133-4452fd61d0de:account\r\n']
(Pdb) s
--Call--
> /python2.7/socket.py(223)meth()
-> def meth(name,self,*args):
(Pdb) n
> /python2.7/socket.py(224)meth()
-> return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
(Pdb) name
'sendall'
(Pdb) self._sock
<socket object, fd=11, family=2, type=1, protocol=6>
(Pdb) s
```